# Converting date from utc to regional setting (cultural info) of the site

Tags: 2010, development, date-time, conversion, regional-settings

I have a question, basically i have a date time which is by default in UTC, how do i programmatically convert it to a correct date time in regional settings of the site collection / or user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For full explanation see [Dealing with Multiple Time Zones in SharePoint 2010](http://www.stum.de/2010/06/10/dealing-with-multiple-time-zones-in-sharepoint-2010/)

```
var user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
// Always perform a Null-Check on SPUser.RegionalSettings
if (user.RegionalSettings != null)
{
    return user.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(listDateUtc);
}
else
{
    // User didn't set a time zone, so use the one from the Web
    return SPContext.Current.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(listDateUtc);
}
```

Comment: Any way you could convert this to JSOM? I tried but can't seem to figure it out.